# JSP funciona normalmente apenas no Localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web dinâmico em JAVA. Estou usando o JAVA 1.8_0121, Tomcat 8.5 e mySQL.

Desde que eu comecei o projeto que eu usei localhost para depurar meu aplicativo, agora estou tentando implantar no meu servidor, quando eu fiz isso, o programa começou a mostrar alguns bugs... O login funciona bem, a pesquisa funciona bem, mas quando eu seleciono objetos para adicionar num carrinho de compras para calcular seus valores, não funciona, muito menos mostra o desconto (desconto percentual) e as vezes a descrição do objeto não aparece.

Acho que não seja problema no código mas alguma configuração do server web que não tenho ideia de onde mexer, muito menos consigo debuggar o JSP na web.

EDIT

Conforme alguns comentários tentei usar o ´Maven´ e mesmo assim não funcionou ele abre apenas o index.jsp depois que efetuo o login da aplicação da Erro 404.

Segue algumas imagens de como organizo o projeto
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT 2

Como posso colocar as pastas do projeto todo no server? Tem alguma maneira de deixar os breakpoint no arquivo war? Como posso debugar fora do localhost?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Você pode postar os códigos do `web.xml` e `pom.xml` (se houver), por favor? Á propósito, como você está fazendo o deploy no seu servidor? Você gera um `.war` e insere no tomcat manualmente?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli estou usando classes que `dao extends` no `HttpServlets` ... não estou usando `Maven Repository`, estou usando Libs que estão adicionadas no `BuildPath`. Estou gerando um `.war` sim e dou deploy manualmente no `Manager App` do `TOMCAT 8.5`

Comment: Como eu disse antes, não estou usando o `Maven`. Estou gerando o `.war` pelo `Export` do `Eclipse`

Comment: Entendi. Tem algum motivo muito grande para você não usar Maven? Pergunto pois particularmente confio muito mais nos builds e `war`s gerados pelo Maven do que os builds e `war`s gerados pelo Eclipse. O Maven é muuuito mais do que só gerenciador de dependências :-)

Comment: Sim, pois algumas libs estavam dando muito problema pelo Maven, eu conheço bastante sobre ele e sei das suas "magias", porem não consegui utilizar ele neste projeto

Comment: 2 “chutes”: (1) Se você está usando servlets, lembre-se que variáveis de instância em servlets são compartilhadas por todos os usuários. (2) Além disso, não aparece nada estranho nos logs do servidor ou nos logs do navegador? Vai que tem algum AJAX sendo bloqueado...

Comment: Acho que não seja problemas com os servlets ou alguma chamada de AJAX (eu nem usei AJAX), até porque a busca de produtos funciona, login também funciona, a aplicação busca corretamente os valores do banco exceto quando adiciono um produto da busca no carrinho de compras ele não trás os valores certos e muitas vezes troca valores, no localhost isso funciona normalmente, e na web não estou conseguindo debugar o JSP diferente do localhost

Comment: Como podem ver, meus JSP's estão dentro do WEB-INF que é uma pasta "protegida" do próprio projeto. As rotas estão funcionando normalmente, porém não estou conseguindo passar a tela de login